# Splitting a file provides some sort of encryption?

Tags: security, pdf, encryption, images

I was wondering if splitting a file with tools like HJsplit provides some sort of encryption.

Imagine I split an image or a pdf in various parts, if someone manage to get just 1 or more parts, could he figure out or gather information about the entire image or maybe reading part of the pdf?

If yes, what would be a good method to prevent this?

Comment: "Encryption is the process of encoding messages or information in such a way that only authorized parties can read it." ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)) In your scenario everyone can or can't read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption is when you scramble data, in this case your data is just incomplete. The data in the parts they have is accessible to them.

Instead of using HJsplit you could always make encrypted split archives. For example 7-zip allows you to make a 7z archive with 256bit AES encryption, and split it into multiple chunks.

[image: 7-zip screenshot of encrypted split 7z file creation]

Answer (score 1):

While most file splitters just split a file, FFSJ-lite ( http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~hoangle/filesj/ ) also offers the ability to encrypt, and password protect splits.

## Steps:

1. Download FFSJ-lite, and run it.
2. Browse for an input file, set an output location, choose split size, check the box for data encryption, and press `Split`.
   [image: split]
3. Choose your password, and press `OK`.
   [image: password prompt]
4. To re-join a file browse for the first split part, choose an output directory, and click join.
   [image: join]
5. You will be prompted to enter the password, do so.
   [image: passprompt]

## Notes:

- No details about the encryption is available in the program manual, I would therefore advise 7-zip over FFSJ-lite if encryption is important.