# Splitting a large VM

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-management, file-transfer

I have a large virtualBox virtual machine 55GB approx. This is currently on my external harddrive. The problem is I am not able to copy it from my external USB hard drive into my pc. At around 75% it just fails the copy. I cant clone it either since its attempting to clone from hard drive to my pc. This must be due to some limitations of my external hard drive, although I cant be so sure. Its only a year old. The only thing I can think of right now is to copy it in pieces of 25GB each and then copy it over and join it back into one. Does anyone have any other options I can try? and if file splitting is the only option, what kind of file splitters would you recommend for splitting and joining large Virtual machine files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have success using a different program to copy the V.M. folder. If not you could always make a split
archive of the V.M. folder, copy the archive over in chunks, and then extract it.

## Alternative Ways To Copy Data:

### Using Xcopy To Copy Directories:

> xcopy "C:\vmfolder" "D:\vmfolder" /E /V /I /F /H /-Y /J

Substitute `C:\vmfolder` for the location of the V.M. folder, and `D:\vmfolder` for the place you want to copy it.

`/E` Copies directory, subdirectories, and all the files in them.

`/V` Will verify the file sizes afterwards.

`/I` Allows specifying destination directory.

`/F` Shows what's being copied while copying.

`/H` Copies hidden files, and system files too.

`/-Y` Prompts you if you're going to overwrite an existing file.

`/J` No input/output buffer is used. Ideal when dealing with large files.

Here's an example:

> xcopy "E:\Virtual Machines\VMware Player\Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64" "F:\Temp\Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64" /E /V /I /F /H /-Y /J

### Using Robocopy To Copy Directories:

> robocopy "C:\vmfolder" "D:\vmfolder" /E /J /SL /MT[:1] /V /FP /ETA /TEE

Substitute `C:\vmfolder` for the location of the V.M. folder, and `D:\vmfolder` for the place you want to copy it.
You can leave `/MT[:1]` as is or if your computer can handle more threads you can increase it.

`/E` Copies subdirectories.

`/J` No buffer is used for inputs/outputs, which is helpful for large files.

`/SL` If symbolic links are used, copy the link not the target.

`/MT[:n]` Multi-threaded copying; min threads is 1, and max is 128. Use a number your system can handle.

`/V` Verbose outputs.

`/FP` Adds fullpath to outputs.

`/ETA` Estimates time to completion.

`/TEE` Output to console in addition to log file.

Here's an example:

> robocopy "E:\Virtual Machines\VMware Player\Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64" "F:\Temp\Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64" /E /J /SL /MT[:1] /V /FP /ETA /TEE

## Creating An Archive, Copying It, And Extracting It

### Using 7-zip Command Line Version To Create A Split Archive:

> C:

Substitute `C:` for the drive you wish to save the archive to.

> cd "C:\savelocation"

Substitute `C:\savelocation` for the spot on the drive you wish to save the archive to. All because 7zip doesn't support
specifying an output path when creating archives (though it does for extracting with `e`).

> 7za a -tzip -r -mx0 -mmt -v5g "vmfolder.zip" "C:\vmfolder"

Substite `vmfolder.zip` for the archive name, and `C:\vmfolder` for the V.M. folder
path.

`a` Adds files to an archive.

`-r` Recursively adds sub-directories.

`-mx0` Sets compression to none.

`-mmt` Enables multi-threading.

`-v` Splits archive into chunks, `g` is for gigabytes, `m` is for megabytes, `k` is for kilobytes, and `b` is for bytes.

`t` Choose archive type, `zip` is for zip archives.

For example:

> E:
>
> cd "E:\Virtual Machines\VMware Player"
>
> 7za a -tzip -r -mx0 -mmt -v300m "Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64.zip" "E:\Virtual Machines\VMware Player\Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64"

### Using Xcopy To Copy Files:

> xcopy "C:\savelocation*.zip*" "D:\savelocation" /V /I /F /H /-Y /J

Substitute `C:\savelocation` for the location of the archives, and `D:\savelocation` for the place you want to copy them.

`/V` Will verify the file sizes afterwards.

`/I` Allows specifying destination directory.

`/F` Shows what's being copied while copying.

`/H` Copies hidden files, and system files too.

`/-Y` Prompts you if you're going to overwrite an existing file.

`/J` No input/output buffer is used. Ideal when dealing with large files.

For example:

> xcopy "E:\Virtual Machines\VMware Player*.zip*" "F:\test" /V /I /F /H /-Y /J

### Using 7-zip Command Line Version To Extract A Split Archive:

> D:

Subsitute `D:` for the drive you wish to extract the archive to.

> cd "D:\extractionlocation"

Subsitute `C:\extractionlocation` for the location on the drive you wish to extract to.

> 7za x -mmt "D:\savelocation\vmfolder.zip.001"

Substiute `D:\savelocation\vmfolder.zip.001` for the location of the archives. When 7-zip creates split archives it a
appends `001`, `002`, and so on to the seperate pieces.

`x` Extracts files, and folders normally.

`-mmt` Enables mult-threading.

For example:

> F:
>
> cd "F:\test"
>
> 7za x -mmt "F:\Virtual Machines\VMware Player\Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Core X86-64.zip.001"

## Notes:

- Failed file transfers under high loads can be an indicator of an underpowered drive.
- 7-zip is released in 2 versions: 7-zip, and 7-zip Command Line Version. 7-zip is G.U.I. only, and 7-zip Command Line Version is C.L.I. only.

Comment: Thanks for that extremely detailed answer. It will take me a while to go thru it all. I think I may have an under powered external drive which is causing this issue. xcopy might have the same issue as doing a CTRL+C -> CTRL+V When I tried to zip the VM using 7Z it kind of went on for almost 90 minutes with only 30% done and then it didnt seem to move on any more.

Comment: how can I find out how many threads my computer can support for using the multi thread option in robocopy?

Comment: @user9623 The # of threads depends on your hardware, primarily the CPU. CPUs have a thread count, sometimes it's equal to the # of cpu cores, sometimes it's double or more. Googling your CPU model should tell you. You also need enough ram for each thread you run, and the drive's read-speed/write-speed/IOPS can be an issue on very slow drives. If you believe your drive may be under-powered then using 1 thread would be advisable. Also, have you tried connecting your external drive to a different usb port, preferably one on the back of your desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Normally there should not be problems copying 55GB file, so you may need to solve this problem. I remember someone has to turn power saving off so the computer willnot to to sleep mode while copying.

Comment: I have several 100+GB VM's and concur. Something's wrong if you're having issues moving, copying or backing up a file this size. Even on external drive and on USB 2.0.

Comment: well I am working on the pc while the copy is going on so it cant be it going in idle or power saving mode

Comment: What error message does Windows show exactly? Are there any error messages stating the USB device went offline in the system event log?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using HJsplit ( http://www.hjsplit.org/ ). It's free, and dumpable (no installation needed).

## Steps:

1. Create a new folder of the same name as the V.M. folder, but on the drive you want the V.M. on.
2. Copy all the small files from the V.M. folder to the new folder.
3. Download HJsplit, and use it to split, and rejoin the larger files.

   - Run HJsplit
   - Choose `Split`
     [image: split]
   - Choose an input file, output location, and split size, then click `start`. Repeat for each file you need to split. It may "appear" to hang at the `100%` mark, but that's just a bug where it tells you 100% of the first file, and then doesn't calculate for the rest; the program is still working.
     [image: choose]
   - Once the splitting process finishes, browse for the split files, and then copy them to the drive you want them on, but do not put them into the new folder.
   - In HJsplit click `Join`.
     [image: Join]
   - Browse for an input file, which will be the first part, it will end in `.001`. Browse for an output location, which will be your previously created new folder that has all the copied small files. Lastly press `start`. You will need to repeat this for all the files you split.
     [image: input join]
   - In HJsplit click `Checksum`.
     [image: checksum]
   - Browse for the original file, and then click `start`. It may "appear" to hang at 100%, but it's still working. You will get a checksum, and repeat the process for the file in your new folder using another instance of HJsplit.
     [image: checksum input]
   - The checksums should match, if they don't your files are not the same!
     [image: match]

## Notes:

- HJsplit will take a while to to split large files. I tested on a 5.5GB-ish file, and it took around 20 minutes; the join process is faster, and the checksum process is equivalent to paint drying.
- You could also use the compare feature to verify your files are the same.

Comment: You may also like FFSJ-lite, which is a free file splitter. See this answer: http://superuser.com/a/828694/363072